# Visual Studio 2022 Debug Console Window Font Size, When Using Windows Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-2022, windows-terminal

I have set Windows Terminal as my default terminal application in windows terminal itself. Now when I debug something in Visual Studio, it brings up, what I believe, is a Windows Terminal window. This is fine, but I have very bad eyesight, so I need to increase the font of these output windows to be able to read them. I cannot find how, or where, to increase the font if Windows Terminal is the default.

I see a "Visual Studio Debug Console" profile in Windows Terminal, but that does not seem to affect the window that opens when I debug from with Visual Studio 2022. Is there a way to set the profile for the terminal it opens ? Or is there some other profile I am missing ?

Currently I see this
[image]

And this is the profile I am talking about
[image]

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-font-size-for-a-windows-terminal

Answer (score 2):

To change the font size for the Windows Terminal profile, click on the "Visual Studio Debug Console", then on the right hand side you will need to scroll down to find `Additional settings`->`Appearance`

Here you'll find **Font face** and **Font size** etc...

[image]

Comment: I have changed it here, it has no affect

Comment: Oh yes you're right, well this certainly should be how to change the font size. IMO MS rolled out Windows Terminal too quickly, there are other issues related to using them, which is why I have reverted to using original Console. This would seem to require submitting a bug report to MS to fix.

Comment: You are right, I should probably stop being so stubborn and revert back to Console. Sad times.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily there is a way to get back the old Console style:

When the new style Terminal Window opens, right click on the empty space of the title bar and select **"Settings"** This should bring you to the `Settings`->`Startup screen`

Change the **"Default terminal application"** to **"Windows Console Host"**

Click "Save"

Comment: But this would change the default for Windows 11 back to Command Prompt, instead of Windows Terminal